# Get class object from generic type

Tags: java, android, generics, reflection

I want to simplify a project by removing useless classes. By useless classes I mean something like :

```
public class MainPage extends TileGridFragment<MainModel> {}
```

The whole logic of this class is implemented by `TileGridFragment`, and the data is provided by `MainModel`, which instance is accessed thanks to a singleton class.

I want to defer the instanciation of such class to a later time, so I simply pass `MainPage.class` to my methods.

As `MainPage` is equivalent to `TileGridFragment<MainModel>`, I would like to remove this class and instead use something like `TileGridFragment<MainModel>.class` instead.

But this doesn't work and I'm out of idead.

I've also tried `Class.forName`, but its throws a `ClassNotFoundException`.

Any idea ?

Comment: You can not do it becourse of "Type Erasure". Generics are compile-time classes http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the implementation of `MainPage` is actually `{}`, just pass `TileGridFragment.class`. The actual type parameters are irrelevant on runtime because they are removed by **erasure**.

Also, because of erasure, you can cast the new `TileGridFragment` (with a raw type, as the result of `TitleGridFragment.class.newInstance()`) to `TitleGridFragment<MainModel>`, and ther will be no collateral damages (other than a little warning from the compiler, that can be supressed).

Answer (score 0):

You can't really, you might get some joy from reflection but I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do.

Try here:
[Get generic type of class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already read this somewhat related question, but it's not the point. I already use such techniques to get the class of `MainModel`, to get back a centralized instance.